# Solve: $T(n) = T(n-1) +(1/n)$ by iteration

Tags: recurrence-relations, contest-math, problem-solving

Use iteration method to solve:

$1.$  $T(n) = T(n-1) + \frac{1}{n},\,(T(0)=1)$

$ 2.$  $T(n) = 3T\left(\dfrac{n}{3}\right) +1,\,(T(3)=1)$

Comment: ...please...? And is it legal to ask this question if it belongs to a contest? And what have you done so far?

Comment: those is a question in my university ( university lebanese ) ... i try it:
T(n)= 1/(n-0) + 1/(n-1) + 1/(n-2) +T(n-3)


T(n)=∑_(i=0)^(k-1)▒1/(n-i) + T(n-k)

Comment: Questions from ongoing contests are not welcome (unless specifically permitted). If it is an old competition, then it is ok, but you should tell us! Also it looks like two questions. You have not specified the range of $n$. If it is supposed to be an integer, then the second part is non-sensical, because $n/3$ may not be an integer. And how hard is it to write it out your testing (for both questions) with $n=1,2,3,...,9,....,27,....$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do the first one for you. Just note that,

$$ T(n) = T(n-1) + \frac{1}{n}=T(n-2) + \frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}$$

$$= T(n-3) + \frac{1}{n-2}+\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}$$

$$ = T(n-4) + \frac{1}{n-3}+\frac{1}{n-2}+\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n} $$

$$ \implies T(n)=T(0)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}=1+H_n, $$

where $H_n$ are the [harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: big thanks for u Mhenni Benghorbal :)